# Find top and average value from input field text

Tags: 7, views

H i have like 2000 nodes with field type - text field.

Purpose of that field is to be filled with best time that someone had on race. Format is something like 02:43:02 ( keep in mind that is text field and not time picker ).

Now i have been asked to show top 10 times, and average time, and im not sure how to do math here if that is text field?

Can views find top 10 times from text field?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP function [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) might help you here:

> strtotime — Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp

For example, you could create a computed field and use that function to convert the text input to a time value.

But as you're using a text field and not a date/time filed, I doubt that you'll be able to get all values correctly (because user input can differ enormously).

Comment: But if im setting this up from scratch with ability to chose field type, what is the best possible combination to accomplish this?

Comment: I suppose you should use something like the [HMS Field](https://drupal.org/project/hms_field). I first thought of the [Date module](https://drupal.org/project/date), but it seems to be more complex as it requires at least a year value.